# How do I get my address and search bars back in Windows 7 Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

I noticed, after a recent Windows Update in Windows 7 (64-bit), that Windows Explorer no longer has the forward/back buttons, address bar or search bar. Is there any way to get them back? (There's no option in the View menu or anywhere else that I can think of.) If not, is there a good add-on that I can download? I've searched for answers to my question and have thus far only turned up old posts that don't help.

Those features are still there in File Save and Open dialogues, but not in Explorer itself.

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 64-bit full yup-to-date and those buttons and address bar are there, so it's not a Windows update that caused it (at least not directly). Doe sit behave the same way if you make a new user account and log in with that?  How about in Safe Mode?  If you suspect the update caused it, does going back using System Restore to a point before the update(s) were installed fix it?

Comment: What version of Windows is it(Ultimate, Proffessional, Home Premium, etc)?

Comment: Have you done an `SFC /Scannow` to ensure all system files are proper, and intact?

Comment: It's the Enterprise version. I just noticed, when I went to save a screen shot to my HD, that the missing features are actually there in the Save dialogue, but for some reason, Explorer itself is missing them. I've added that fact to the question.

Comment: @techie007: SFC found no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the computer that I was having this problem on was my computer at work, I really didn't have much time to look into why it was happening. Since we were allowed to leave early today, I decided to take techie007's advice and try Safe Mode. It worked there, so I rebooted to see if just being in Safe Mode fixed the problem (as I've discovered that it did for other minor problems I've had on my computers, both at home and at work, in the past. Sure enough, I have the navigation controls back on Windows Explorer now.